# Terminology: Is this a combination, permutation, or something else?

Tags: combinations, permutation, terminology

I'm writing an article and want to discuss how adding another dimension can greatly increase the number of possible values, and am looking for the correct term for something. For example, if t-shirts come in 7 sizes and 5 colors then there are 35 possible *?*'s. And if we add collar style as a variable with 2 possible values, then we double the number of *?*'s to 70. What is the correct term for this? I first thought of combinations and permutations, but their mathematical definitions at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation do not match this situation. Both refer to selections from a single pool of values; in my case I have separate pools of values for each position in the result. Is there a correct term for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct combinatorial term is [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) (set of all tuples (ordered pairs, triplets etc))